# Telegram api. Get all uploaded photos by media_group_id

Tags: html, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I send to my telegram bot a few photos as group. How I can get the `file_id` all of my uploaded photos?

I use webhooks, but response is not contain any data about all photos, just some data about last uploaded photo and `media_group_id`. How I can get all `file_id`'s of my uploaded group photos

response:
[image]

Comment: You have to receive several updates, and them have the same `media_group_id`.

Comment: Yes, this is a good way to get photos of the one group, but in my logic, after upload the last photo, webhook must call function for send message to user, for this I need to know when the last photo was uploaded

Comment: interesting fact - the "date" element in response is the same in all of webhooks. I upload 5 photos and receive 5 response with the same date element. This means that you can detect group photos by media_group_id or time element

Comment: @AlexeyShablowski did you find a solution? I have the same problem and I get only last photo on publishing multiple photos message. After that on the next published message (if any) I receive all the rest from that media group. Not consistent at all since I can't get all the images until any other random message is published.

Comment: When using `sendMediaGroup` it returns array of `Message`.

Answer (score 2):

The Telegram Bot API does not give to your web-hook any reliable information about the order of each item in a media group. https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message

Suggestions:

1. If bot is in a private chat, save the incoming `file_id` against their `media_group_id`. Whenever `media_group_id` changes you would have all you need to use. Engage the user in some other way so that you can quickly determine the `media_group_id` change and respond quickly from that processing.
2. If bot is in a group chat, save incoming `file_id` against the users `id` as well as `media_group_id` and similarly monitor changes to `media_group_id` and user `id` to take action.

When a solution starts getting too complex for my liking, I prefer to go back to the basic reason for my need and perhaps find out that I do not need to do something an API doesn't afford like "Get all uploaded photos by `media_group_id`". Maybe I can just process them individually as the updates stream in.

Tip: If the media group has a `caption` and you only care about the first media item in the group, then monitoring the `media_group_id` and `caption` of an incoming message should be sufficient.

`if(message.caption != null && message.media_group_id != null){
    // first item in new group received
}`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this way is **not simple** and **not elegant** but it's working.

1. We need to see in webhook response `media_group_id` element - this means that this is a group of media.
2. If the first point is true - save the data about this media on own server (data must be contain `media_group_id`)

> example: ["media_group_id" => [[some data about photo]]]

3. When next webhook is come, we need to see his `media_group_id`, if it's the same - ok, add him to array...

> example: ["media_group_id" => [[some data about photo],[some data about photo]]]

if not - ok, make a new element of array:

> example: ["media_group_id" => [[some data about photo]], "media_group_id2" =>
>   [[some data about photo]]]

4. So we got an array that contains all data about the photos of the one(or more) group.

*hmmm... I don't like this way, but how make better?*

Comment: I'm interested in a better way of doing this if possible. I want to achieve some processing on a bulk of images (i.e an album)

Answer (score 0):

In Pyrogram, we can use the get_media_group function, https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/get_media_group.html#pyrogram.Client.get_media_group. in my opinion, it is much better than using BOT API.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is not BotApi though, which the user seemingly prefers to use for the given use case.

Comment: Pyrogram can be used with bot_logins. In my opinion, it is much better than using the BOT API.